# TCP listener/client client force close

Tags: c#, tcp

I have been making a TCP server, where you could create an account and login to it. Server would then make a Notepad with your account data.

I am having problem with clients closing the connection, and the server stops.

Can anyone fix this code? Don't mind the length, I have been testing and experimenting a lot of stuff, so the code may seem to long, but this isn't the "final" project, it's just a test version.

```
public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
        tcpclnt.Connect("IP", 500);
        // use the ipaddress as in the server program

        Console.Write("Write: Create/Login");
        Console.WriteLine();

        String str_ = Console.ReadLine();
        Stream stm1 = tcpclnt.GetStream();

        ASCIIEncoding asen_ = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] ba_ = asen_.GetBytes(str_);
        stm1.Write(ba_, 0, ba_.Length);
        if (str_ == "Create")
        {
        start1:
            string Order = "";
            Stream stm2 = tcpclnt.GetStream();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Username:");
            String usernam = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] usern = asen_.GetBytes(usernam);
            stm2.Write(usern, 0, usern.Length);
            byte[] Code = new byte[100];
            int St = stm2.Read(Code, 0, 100);
            for (int a = 0; a < St; a++)
            {
                Order += Convert.ToChar(Code[a]);
            }
            if (Order == "Error")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Username already exist! Choose another one! Press Enter");
                Console.ReadLine();

                goto start1;
            }
            else
            {
                Order = "";
                Stream stm3 = tcpclnt.GetStream();
                Console.WriteLine("Password:");
                String Passwor = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] Pass = asen_.GetBytes(Passwor);
                stm3.Write(Pass, 0, Pass.Length);
                byte[] Code1 = new byte[100];
                int St1 = stm3.Read(Code1, 0, 100);
                for (int a = 0; a < St1; a++)
                {
                    Order += Convert.ToChar(Code1[a]);
                }
                if (Order == "Created")
                {
                    Order = "";
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Account created!");
                    Stream stm4 = tcpclnt.GetStream();

                    String IDoutput = Console.ReadLine();
                    byte[] IDout = asen_.GetBytes(IDoutput);
                    stm4.Write(IDout, 0, IDout.Length);
                    byte[] Code2 = new byte[100];
                    int St2 = stm4.Read(Code2, 0, 100);
                    for (int a = 0; a < St2; a++)
                    {
                        Order += Convert.ToChar(Code2[a]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("This is your ID:" + Order + ". Remember it, u will use it to login!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    tcpclnt.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        if (str_ == "Login")
        {
        start3:
            string Order = "";
            Stream stm2 = tcpclnt.GetStream();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("ID:");
            String usernam = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] usern = asen_.GetBytes(usernam);
            stm2.Write(usern, 0, usern.Length);

            Stream stm3 = tcpclnt.GetStream();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Password:");
            String usernam1 = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] usern1 = asen_.GetBytes(usernam1);
            stm3.Write(usern1, 0, usern1.Length);
            byte[] Code = new byte[100];
            int St = stm2.Read(Code, 0, 100);
            for (int a = 0; a < St; a++)
            {
                Order += Convert.ToChar(Code[a]);
            }
            if (Order == "Correct")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct");
                Console.ReadLine();
                tcpclnt.Close();
            }
            if (Order == "Wrong")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Combination is incorrect, please try again");
                Console.ReadLine();
                goto start3;
            }
        }
        Stream stm_ = tcpclnt.GetStream();
        byte[] bb_ = new byte[100];
        int k_ = stm_.Read(bb_, 0, 100);

        String str = Console.ReadLine();
        Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
        Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

        stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
        bool c = false;
        byte[] bb = new byte[100];
        int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);
        string ReadID = "";
        string ReadLine = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            if (bb[i] != '*' && c == false)
                ReadID += Convert.ToChar(bb[i]);
            else
                for (int a = i + 1; a < k; a++)
                {
                    i++;
                    c = true;
                    ReadLine += Convert.ToChar(bb[a]);
                }

        Console.WriteLine(ReadID);
        Console.WriteLine(ReadLine);
        Console.ReadLine();
        tcpclnt.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("IP");

            Console.WriteLine("Starting TCP listener...");

            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 500);

            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Socket client = listener.AcceptSocket();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted.");
                string ReadID = "";
                string ReadLine = "";

                string password = "";
                string Order = "";
                var childSocketThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    byte[] data__ = new byte[100];
                    int size__ = client.Receive(data__);
                    for (int a = 0; a < size__; a++)
                    {
                        Order += Convert.ToChar(data__[a]);
                    }
                    if (Order == "Create")
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                        start:
                            string username = "";
                            byte[] data_ = new byte[100];
                            int size_ = client.Receive(data_);
                            for (int a = 0; a < size_; a++)
                            {
                                username += Convert.ToChar(data_[a]);
                            }
                            System.IO.StreamReader reader =
                               new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Gregor\Desktop\USernames.txt");
                            string line_ = "";
                            int o = 0;
                            while ((line_ = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                if (line_ == username)
                                {
                                    client.Send(asen.GetBytes("Error"));
                                    reader.Close();
                                    goto start;
                                }
                            }
                            reader.Close();
                            client.Send(asen.GetBytes("OK"));
                            byte[] dataa = new byte[100];
                            int sizea = client.Receive(dataa);
                            for (int a = 0; a < sizea; a++)
                            {
                                password += Convert.ToChar(dataa[a]);
                            }
                            string[] lines = { username, password };
                            System.IO.StreamReader reader2 =
                               new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Gregor\Desktop\IDcount.txt");
                            string idcounter = "";
                            idcounter = reader2.ReadLine();
                            int idcounterint;
                            bool idcounte = Int32.TryParse(idcounter, out idcounterint);

                            idcounterint++;
                            idcounter = Convert.ToString(idcounterint);
                            reader2.Close();
                            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Gregor\Desktop\IDcount.txt", idcounter);

                            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Gregor\Desktop\User" + idcounter + ".txt", lines);
                            reader.Close();
                            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\Gregor\Desktop\Usernames.txt", (username + Environment.NewLine));

                            client.Send(asen.GetBytes("Created"));
                            client.Send(asen.GetBytes(idcounter));
                            username = "";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (Order == "Login")
                    {
                        byte[] data1 = new byte[100];
                        int size1 = client.Receive(data1);
                        for (int a = 0; a < size1; a++)
                        {
                            ReadID += Convert.ToChar(data1[a]);
                        }
                        byte[] data2 = new byte[100];
                        int size2 = client.Receive(data2);
                        for (int a = 0; a < size2; a++)
                        {
                            password += Convert.ToChar(data2[a]);
                        }
                        System.IO.StreamReader reader1 =
                              new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Gregor\Desktop\User" + ReadID + ".txt");
                        string read1 = reader1.ReadLine();
                        string read2 = reader1.ReadLine();

                        if (password == read2)
                        {
                            client.Send(asen.GetBytes("Correct"));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            client.Send(asen.GetBytes("Wrong"));
                        }
                    }

                    byte[] data = new byte[100];
                    int size = client.Receive(data);

                    bool c = false;

                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    {
                        if (data[i] != ' ' && c == false)
                            ReadID += Convert.ToChar(data[i]);
                        else
                            for (int a = i + 1; a < size; a++)
                            {
                                c = true;
                                ReadLine += Convert.ToChar(data[i]);
                            }
                    }
                    int ReadID_;
                    bool result = Int32.TryParse(ReadID, out ReadID_);

                    int counter = 0;
                    string line = "";
                    string ID = ReadID;
                    string rLine = "";

                    System.IO.StreamReader file =
                       new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Gregor\Desktop\User" + ReadID + ".txt");
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (counter == ReadID_)
                            rLine = line;
                        counter++;
                    }

                    file.Close();

                    client.Send(asen.GetBytes(ID + "*" + rLine));

                    Console.WriteLine();

                    client.Close();
                });
                childSocketThread.Start();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.StackTrace);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Don't mind the long code"_? Of course we mind the long code, this is way too much for us to read. If you have not pinpointed the problem to a little more specific location, and thus cannot create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there's probably no one that will want to go through all that. -- You should try to structure your code better in order to achieve easier pinpointing of problems.

Comment: You're also missing an explanation about when it closes. You should probably look into [**message framing**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37352525/3740093) as that will help you handle the data sent/received via the sockets.

Comment: Consider using a real web server/service rather than doing everything from scratch. If you're doing this as a learning experience, be aware that writing correct, scalable, secure network code isn't easy. What you've got certainly has a long way to go before it could qualify.