# How to read two or more files from NetworkStream with tcp client and tcplistener

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, stream, tcpclient

I am making a simple project that consists of 2 programs, a client and a server. I am using TCP to communicate between the server and the client and would like to transfer files from client to server. I already know how to do it for one file, but not for two or more.

**QUESTION**

I know how to put multiple files into a stream (I think) but not how to read it on the server side. How do I do this?

I have the following **pseudo code**:

**SERVER PROGRAM**

```
using (TcpClient mClient = (TcpClient)client)
            {
                using (NetworkStream stream = mClient.GetStream())
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[2048];

                    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Projects\imageLOL.png"))
                    {
                        file.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                    stream.Close();
                }
                mClient.Close();
            }
```

**CLIENT PROGRAM**

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                updateIP();
                client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ipadres), 49181);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
            try
            {
                using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    byte[] message1 = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath1); // file 1
                    byte[] message2 = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath2); // file 2

                    stream.Write(message1, 0, message1.Length);
                    stream.Write(message2, 0, message2.Length);

                    stream.Close();
                }
                client.Close();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to implement [**message framing**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37352525). Keep in mind that you shouldn't send too large files though. Rather split them into parts.

Comment: @VisualVincent the answer doesnt say what to use the header for and what type of data to use for header so it is always 1 byte, also this still isnt the answer to my question: how to read two files or more from a buffer?

Comment: It does say what to use the header for, however I agree with you that it is not very clear: _"...and then determine what you will do with it (depending on the header, that is)"_.

Comment: @VisualVincent but why they assume the header is only 1 byte? Which data type do I need to use to only use only 1 byte?

Comment: The header indicates what kind of packet you're sending/receiving, and it is a header of your choice. `and what type of data to use for header so it is always 1 byte` - Use a [**Byte**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I am the author of the answer. You can use a multi-byte header if you like, but it is a bit more complex and unnecessary since a byte can ranges from 0-255 which means you can have 256 different headers.

Comment: @VisualVincent allrigjt so with this header that is a byte i can send a additional number that represents extra information about my file. How can a number represent this informayion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131191/discussion-between-visual-vincent-and-nahro).

Comment: @VisualVincent hey can you look at chat? i wrote a part