# Sending Files over VB.Net using net sockets

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net and net-sockets to establish a connection in the form of server-client. I have accomplished the task of communication between the server and the client. However, I'm having trouble for sending files and receiving them. I don't even know where to start. I tried to refer some codes. But didn't understand it quite clearly. 
Please help me with the sending and receiving part.

Comment: Start by just sending the filesize with an integer. After you can do that, send the bytes in the actual file.

Comment: If you're using TCP look into [**message framing**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341382/c-sharp-deserializing-a-struct-after-receiving-it-through-tcp/37352525#37352525).