# Wait unit an event is raised

Tags: vb.net, tcp, wait

I'm trying to make a code that waits until an event is raised. I used the answer in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233852/tcp-client-to-server-communication/35240061#35240061) page for Tcp communication. The `event` `PacketReceived` will be raised when a packet is received.

```
Private Sub FooBar()
    'Send some Tcp Message here`

    'Wait until a reply is received here

    'Execute some code when reply is received

End Sub
```

This is code Sends the filename and what's the file for. It lacks of file existence checking

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim t = New Thread(AddressOf SendFile)
        Dim f = New FileAndData
        f.FileList = SlideShowItems
        f.FileType = "tempSlideShowImage"
        t.Start(f)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendFile(obj As Object)
        Dim fD = CType(obj, FileAndData)
        For Each item In fD.FileList.Items
            Dim fileIn As New FileStream(item, FileMode.Open)
            Const chunkSize = 10485760

            Dim messageFileNamePkt As New TcpMessagePacket(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Path.GetFileName(item)), TcpMessagePacket.PacketHeader.Filename)
            messageFileNamePkt.Send(_etcClient.Client) 'Send file name

            Dim messageFiletype As New TcpMessagePacket(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(fD.FileType), TcpMessagePacket.PacketHeader.Filetype)
            messageFiletype.Send(_etcClient.Client) 'Send file type

            'Wait here for reply if for file existence

            While fileIn.Position < fileIn.Length
                Dim bytes(chunkSize) As Byte
                If fileIn.Length - fileIn.Position < bytes.Length Then
                    ReDim bytes(fileIn.Length - fileIn.Position - 1)
                End If
                fileIn.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

                Dim messageFilePkt As New TcpMessagePacket(bytes, TcpMessagePacket.PacketHeader.FileData)
                messageFilePkt.Send(_etcClient.Client) 'Send file chunks

            End While

            fileIn.Close()
            Dim messageFileEnd As New TcpMessagePacket(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(""), TcpMessagePacket.PacketHeader.TransferComplete)
            messageFileEnd.Send(_etcClient.Client) 'Send transfer complete

        Next
    End Sub

Public Class FileAndData
    Public FileList As ListBox
    Public FileType As String
End Class
```

And this is the handler for the reply

```
    Private Sub Client_PacketReceived(sender As Object, e As ExtendedTcpClient.PacketReceivedEventArgs) Handles _etcClient.PacketReceived
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there! It's a nice implementation of my code you have here, however there are two things I'd like to point out that could make it a bit more efficient: **1)** A chunk size of 10485760 bytes (10 MB) is _very_ much to put into the network buffer for each send and will most likely slow things down greatly. -- From conducting my own tests I have found that the ideal buffer size is 8192-32768 (8-32 KB) - even over LAN. Everything above and below those values caused the sending to go much slower.

Comment: (Had to split this into two comments): **2)** When sending packets with no data, instead of `Encoding.Default.GetBytes("")` you could just do: `New Byte() {}` to create an empty byte array. The execution speed difference between the two will likely only be a few hundred microseconds up to a millisecond, but it's still an improvement that removes unnecessary processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ManualResetEvent`. Ex.

```
Imports System.Threading
Module Module1
    Private ReadOnly WaitEvent As New ManualResetEvent(True)
    Sub Main()
        For i = 1 To 100
            WaitEvent.WaitOne() 'This is like a door. It's open because of ManualResetEvent(True)
            If i = 50 Then
                WaitEvent.Reset() 'This closes the door
            End If
            Console.WriteLine(i)
        Next
        Console.Read()
    End Sub
    Private Sub SetTheEventWhenCalled()
        WaitEvent.Set() 'This on the other hand, Opens the door
    End Sub
End Module
```