# Resizing form with anchored image (from MemoryStream) causes 'System.ArgumentException' and 'The application is in break mode'

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a `TcpListener` which gets an endless stream of `byte array`. From that, I convert the byte() to MemoryStream and feed a PictureBox to display the images. That works fine. 
If I set the anchor points on the PictureBox to `top/right/bottom/left` which means the image will expand when the form expands and **then I actually expand** the form, I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.
```

Also,

```
The application is in break mode
```

Code

```
 ' Enter the listening loop.
        While True
            Dim client As TcpClient = Await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync()
            Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream
            Dim MS As New MemoryStream
            Await stream.CopyToAsync(MS)
            Await ViewImage(MS)
            client.Close()
        End While
```

View image function:

```
   Public Async Function ViewImage(ms As MemoryStream) As Task
        Try
            Dim myimage As Bitmap
            myimage = New Bitmap(ms)
            PictureBox1.Image = myimage
            PictureBox1.Refresh()
            myimage.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Function
```

Please note that the exception is not caught within my code. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that _**the entire**_ image is received? Since TCP is a stream-based protocol the application layer has no knowledge of packets/the length of your data. You can either try serializing/deserializing the image over the stream using _Binary Serialization_, or see [**this answer of mine**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35240061/3740093) which helps you split the data into packets of your own (known as _message framing_).

Comment: Oh wait, missed that you were closing the connection once the image has been received. Then it's not related to the data or packet size (though what I said above could be a good thing to consider in the future ;)).

Comment: Glad I could help! I don't know how much you know about reference/value types, but I added a basic example to my answer for those who don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is most likely related to the fact that you ***dispose*** `myimage` at the end of your `ViewImage()` method.

This:

```
PictureBox1.Image = myimage
...
myimage.Dispose()
```

makes `myimage` and `PictureBox1.Image` point to the same `Bitmap` object. Bitmaps are reference types (classes) which means that you're just passing their reference pointer around when you assign it to different variables.

Thus when you dispose `myimage` you are disposing the same image that is being shown in the `PictureBox`, which could cause that error of yours when GDI+ tries to redraw a stretched version of it (as a matter of fact not even the original image should be displayed once you've disposed it).

For more info see: [**Value Types and Reference Types - Microsoft Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types).

---

**Basic example of how Reference Types and Value Types work**

Reference types:

```
Dim A As New Bitmap("image.bmp")

Dim B As Bitmap = A 'Points to A.
PictureBox1.Image = A 'Points to A.
PictureBox2.Image = B 'Still points to A.

'Calling Dispose() on any of the above will result in none of them having an image since you will ultimately dispose bitmap A.
```

Value types:

```
Dim A As Integer = 3

Dim B As Integer = A 'Copy of A.
Dim C As Integer = B 'Copy of B.

C = 4 'Results in A = 3, B = 3, C = 4.
```